# issue with importing csv file in r

Tags: r, csv, dataset, readr

i am trying to read CSV file in R using readr package and read_csv function

```
library(readr)
read_csv(choose.file())
```

but this Error appear to me :

> Error in guess_header_(datasource, tokenizer, locale) : 
>     Cannot read file C:/Users/salsa/Desktop/daily_SPEC_2014.csv/daily_SPEC_2014.csv: Not enough storage is available to process this command.

So, what is the problem here !!

Thanx

Comment: The error looks pretty self-explanatory to me. The CSV file is probably too large to be read in memory.

Comment: Maybe `data.table` could help? How big is the file?

Comment: I'd review how you are choosing your path, having ~.csv/~.csv may cause an issue as readR may parse that incorrectly. Otherwise, as others have suggested, if your file is too big, try data.table, or consider other options for storage

Comment: Is that definitely a valid path?

Comment: thank you all , the problem was in the memory capacity of RAM , the file has more than 2 million observation , when i restarted my laptop it worked well